# Wordpress : change menu labels on mouse-over

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu, label

I'd like to be able to change the wordpress menu labels for some other texts when the mouse pass over it. Here's a pict of what I am aiming :

[image](http://habanita.free.fr/menulabel.png)

Can someone point me some directions ? Any Jquery trick ? CSS hack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a pure CSS/HTML solution? The below has the added benefit of maintaining the correct content/style separation and having a minimal code footprint.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TJBu5/1/)

HTML

```
<a href='#' data-englishLabel='School' data-chineseLabel='學校'></a>
```

CSS

```
a:before {
    content:attr(data-chineseLabel);
}
a:hover:before {
    content:attr(data-englishLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tVeu/)

Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("list_one");

elem.onmouseover= function(){
  this.value = "Something Else";
}

elem.onmouseout= function(){
  this.value = "Original text";
}
```

---

CSS version:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDBgh/)

HTML:

```
<div id="list_one">Original Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
#list_one::before{
  content:'Something Else';
  position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
}

#list_one{
    position:relative;
}

#list_one:hover{
    visibility:hidden;
}

#list_one:hover::before{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for this very complete and fast answer !

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help you! Don't forget to vote and mark as accepted! :) @user3592164